# Start Selenium driver server programmatically before opening browser in a remote machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Whenever we use RemoteWebDriver to execute selenium-webdriver tests in remote machine, we need to start up selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar in remote machine. So far, I am doing it manually using the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar
```

Is there anyway I can do it programmatically before starting up remote browser. Below is the code I am using to drive ff in remote browser:

```
// Declare firefox capabilities
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

// Create a remote web driver 
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

// Navigate to test site
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to programmatically start the server in the remote machine(node) from the current machine(hub)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this is not directly possible. To execute commands on a remote machine, you need to have an application running on the remote machine that serves as a listener - waiting for commands that come through. This is what selenium-server-standalone basically achieves (and beyond that it then kickstarts the tests). Hence, the easiest way to do this would be to start selenium-server manually or as a workaround, you can execute a script at a preset time (I execute an ant build as an alarm on a Mac).

Either way you look at it, you need a server which provides SSH running on the remote machine for you to establish a connection for your application on the hub to kickstart something in the node.

My workaround for this was to set up an alarm (on a Mac - you can find similar scripts for Windows) to run an ant task at a certain time which will start the server. The server is started about two minutes before the actual tests are run to give the server time to register with the node.